# Oracle SQL PLS-00049: bad bind variable on Trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I'm getting this error i try to fix it without success, i have controlled the table that i use to to this trigger but it doesn't work. 
this is the code,

```
create or replace TRIGGER INSERISCITURNO
 instead of insert on VistaTurno  for each row
  declare
 ok boolean;
  begin
         ok := false;
  for i in (select a.Giocatore from AVATAR a where a.Partita = :new.Partita ) loop
  if (:new.Giocatore = i.Giocatore) then
    insert into TURNO(CodTurno, NumTurno, Partita, Giocatore) values (:new.CodTurno, :new.NumTurno, :new.Partita, :new.Giocatore);
      AggiornaSituazioneGiocatore(:new.Giocatore, :new.CodTurno, :new.Partita);
      ok := true;
    end if;
    end loop;

    if(ok = false) then
    dbms_output.put_line('Il giocatore è in partita, inserimento fallito!');
    end if;
end;
```

they give me this error on compilation,

```
Errore(8,68): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.PARTITA'
Errore(9,11): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.GIOCATORE'
Errore(10,75): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.CODTURNO'
Errore(10,90): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.NUMTURNO'
Errore(10,105): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.PARTITA'
Errore(10,119): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.GIOCATORE'
Errore(11,39): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.GIOCATORE'
Errore(11,55): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.CODTURNO'
Errore(11,70): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.PARTITA'
```

pls, can someone help me? i think the syntax is good.

add VistaTurno

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW VISTATURNO (
     "CODTURNO", "NUMTURNO", "PARTITA", "GIOCATORE"
 ) AS
 select * from TURNO;
```

and this is the Turno

```
create table TURNO (
CodTurno integer primary key ,
NumTurno integer not null ,
Partita integer,
Giocatore integer
);

alter table TURNO
add constraint  v4 check  (NumTurno > 0);

alter table TURNO
add constraint  fk1 FOREIGN KEY (Partita) REFERENCES PARTITA(CodPartita);

alter table TURNO
 add constraint  fk2 FOREIGN KEY (Giocatore) REFERENCES 
  GIOCATORE(CodGiocatore);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkemO.jpg)

Comment: Can you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54311156/edit) to add the definition of VistaTurno - at least the column names (e.g. describe it)? It looks like it just doesn't have the column names you're trying to refer to with `:new`.

Comment: yes, now i add the Vista Turno.

Comment: i update the form, first i verify the name of the column but i don't understand this error, the name of the column are correct.

Comment: With the definitions you've shown [your trigger compiles successfully](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=07fe00b47738856a6633b1bc57087dfb), so something isn't right in what you've posted.

Comment: this is the code that i use to compile on sql developer, probably is the program? there aren't error in the code right?

Comment: It works fine in SQL Developer too (current version, but can't see any reason an earlier version would have had a problem with it; which version are you using?). You definitely don't have a `referencing` clause you left out when posting? Also the line and column numbers in the errors don't seem to quite match your code, which might be from accidentally changing the formatting when posting, but is a bit confusing.

Comment: i update the code with the line number. just wait and sorry this is my first post here.

Comment: i think the better way to see the error is add a screenshot of the report

Comment: `instead of ` insert, or should that be `before/after insert` ..?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan - no, it's an instead-of trigger against a view, so that's right.

Comment: thanks @AlexPoole, illuminated.

Comment: I have a very faint recollection that at one stage SQL Developer treated bind variables as case sensitive....  Not sure but could try converting all your :new to :NEW and give it a go as the code looks like it should work.

Comment: i try to convert the in :NEW, and it didn't work, same error.

Comment: As the line numbers are wrong it does still look like maybe a client problem, so which version of SQL Developer are you using, and can you upgrade to [the current version](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html)? Or use a different client - try your code through SQL\*Plus for instance.

Comment: Possible issue is that you have used double quotes round your column names in your view.  This means that you need to reference them in the same case (upper) as you created them in your trigger you have mixed case.  Try re-creating your view without the double quotes OR converting your trigger to have the column names in upper case.